Add image in Image Field with PDF Forms
I got PDF Forms with Text field and Image Field. How to I add image from Image field?
For text field in document pypdf that show great information and I success. But I fails to add image in Image Field. Any one can help me.

The format PDF does not have any "image fields". Adobe Acrobat improvised something like image fields from a button field, but the value is not stored in the value of that field type, only in its appearance. So essentially you have to analyze the appearance of the "image field" button.

@mkl ouh I see.  Did you have experience to add image in pdf. ? Which pip package is available for add image in pdf. Thanks for response

PyMuPDF is capable of writing images into specified rectangles on PDF pages. Just like also text or vector graphics. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

@aideed "Did you have experience to add image in pdf. ? Which pip package is available for add image in pdf." - my experiences are limited to have and .NET based code, so sorry, I don't know which pip package can help. You may consider adding the image to the static page content as Jorj proposed. If that works and if the recipient only evaluated the forms visually, not electronically, you may be fine.
